# WPF: Map UserControl properties to its children

Tags: wpf, user-controls

The short version of my question is: Can properties of the UserControl be made available to the children of the UserControl without applying to the UserControl at the same time?

The long version: I am trying to create a "ButtonInput" which is a text box with a bitmap button at the right side, inside of the text box's border. This is pretty much how the search boxes look on many web sites (or in Visual Studio), with a magnifying glass at the right side.

The UserControl definition is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Controls.ButtonInput"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Border 
                    Name="Border"
                    CornerRadius="6" 
                    Padding="4"
                    Margin="2 2 2 2"
                    Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ButtonInput, AncestorLevel=1}}"
                    BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ButtonInput, AncestorLevel=1}}"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                >
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tbInput" 
                             Grid.Column="0" 
                             MaxLines="1" 
                             Background="Transparent"
                             Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ButtonInput, AncestorLevel=1}}"
                             Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ButtonInput, AncestorLevel=1}}"
                             BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <Button Width="24" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image x:Name="imgIcon"
                                        Source="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ButtonInput, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I place this control in a test Window.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="380" Width="402">
            <Label Content="Password" Width="75" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <controls:ButtonInput x:Name="biTest" Source="Resources/img/password.png" Width="300" Height="35" Background="Orange" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="Black" ButtonClick="ButtonInput_ButtonClick" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem I have is that I expect to have only what is inside the border colored orange, but instead the orange bleeds outside the border. I traced the problem to the way the Live Visual Tree looks like:

```
(ButtonInput)
   (Border)
      (ContentPresenter)
         (Grid)
            Border (Border)
               (Grid)
                  tbInput (TextBox)
                  (Button)
```

The first Border is not in my control definition, but its background is Orange as inherited from the ButtonInput.

I did try an alternative: instead of using child controls for the content of the UserControl, I used a ControlTemplate with the same content. In this case, the executable looked OK (rounded rectangle with black border and orange background, no bleeding outside the border), but the designer in Visual Studio does not show anything. There is literally a blank space where the ButtonInput should be.

So, is there a way to prevent the properties set on the UserControl to apply to the first Border? Background is one example but there are other properties that I want to make use of the same way.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that your "ButtonInput" control isn't actually a button, it's a user control which just so happens to have a button on it. So when you set the background in the `<controls:ButtonInput>` tag on your main window you're effectively saying "ignore everything this user control says about the color of it's entire background because I'm now overriding it".

There are several ways around this, but the easiest one from the UserControl's perspective is to use the one last weapon in its arsenal: the template. Overriding the template in a control effectively says "I'm no longer going to be displayed the way a control of my type normally is, so all the usual settings won't apply unless I explicitly use them. That's as simple as doing this in your ButtonInput xaml:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>

        <!-- all your old xaml code goes here -->
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Border 
                    Name="Border"
                    CornerRadius="6" 
                    Padding="4"
        <!--             etc                  -->

    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

Truth be told, there are few cases in WPF where custom controls are actually needed, and this is almost certainly one of them. WPF is more than capable of supporting functionality like this with styles and templates alone. But this answer should suit your needs in the short term.

EDIT: If you want the control to be visible in the designer then populate it with a regular control and template that instead, it's what you probably should be doing anyway. Now your xaml should look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTestApp.Controls.ButtonInput"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             x:Name="_this">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Border 
                        Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="6" 
                        Padding="4"
                        Margin="2 2 2 2"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                    >
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbInput" 
                                 Grid.Column="0" 
                                 MaxLines="1" 
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 Text="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                 BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,-1,0,1"/>
                        <Button Width="24" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image x:Name="imgIcon" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

            </Grid>

        </ControlTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button x:Name="biTest" Width="300" Height="35" Background="Orange" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="Black" Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" />

</UserControl>
```

You haven't addressed the Text binding in your question, the code above is expecting a dependency property in the UserControl code behind:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonInput), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
```

And you now use it like this:

```
<controls:ButtonInput x:Name="biTest" Width="300" Height="35" Text="{Binding MyText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Mark, thank you for your answer. I actually did try that. But with the ControlTemplate, the designer does not show the control on the test window. It's simply blank.

Comment: OK, Clarification: the app shows the control just fine. But the designer in Visual Studio does not. It makes it hard to design an UI with invisible controls :-)